# PHPWord Bullet List Color Change

Tags: phpword

Is it possible to change the bullet color to be any other color aside from black in PHPWord?
I tried adding color to both the list and the text, but nothing seems to work.

```
$phpWord->addFontStyle('myOwnStyle', array('color' => 'FF0000'));
$phpWord->addParagraphStyle('P-Style', array('spaceAfter' => 95));
$predefinedMultilevel = array('color' => 'FF0000', 'listType' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\ListItem::TYPE_BULLET_EMPTY);

$section->addText('Predefined list.'));
$section->addListItem('List Item 1'), 0, 'myOwnStyle', $predefinedMultilevel, 'P-Style');
```

Comment: Yes, I have the same requirement but it always default to black

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```css
    background: #fff;
    list-style: square;
    list-style-type: square;
```